# How to manage content on the same vertical line inside a container without Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I have been using Bootstrap for some time, and it gave me a chance to practice CSS and do some landing pages. The thing is, Bootstrap comes with a lot of classes already declared. You don't have to worry about layout and all the stuff (as you all already know that). I started practicing HTML/CSS but without Bootstrap.

In Bootstrap I always had that pattern :

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-12">
         Content
       </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

That gave me a chance to have everything inside of a precompiled container and didn't have to worry about layout.
Now I'm having some trouble understanding how should my structure look like when I don't use Bootstrap, in a let's say landing page where every section has the same margin and everything is contained inside of bootstrap-like container with margins on left and right sides.

How should I do my CSS and containers to have a good layout for a landing page?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do CSS and containers to have a good layout for a landing page. Infact you can be good at it in max 2 days. [CSS Web Layouts](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_website_layout.asp) , It is all you need to practice and be good at it asap.